# Java syntax error on `System.out.println()` method call

Tags: java, syntax-error

I'm sorry for the extremely short question, but i don't even know why i have this error:

`Syntax error on token "println", = expected after this token`

In this code:

```
static long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
public void testSort5() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int number;
    int[] arr = new int[1000];
    for (int counter = 1; counter < 1000; counter++) {
        number = 1 + random.nextInt(1000);
        arr[counter] = number;
    }
    int[] actual = MergeSort.sort(arr);
}
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Execution time was " + (end - start) + " ms.");
```

Answer (score 12):

You have statements **outside** your method body.

Comment: I already have like 50+ projects created in my current eclipse, yet I faced thise and passed by; Don't jusdge people, rough days can do more than this xD

Answer (score 4):

Your last two lines:

```
long end ...
System.out.println...
```

Appear to be outside of any method. You can't just run code outside of a method, **unless** it's a variable/constant declaration, a class declaration, or other special situations. This is why you get the syntax error on the `System.out.println(...)` call, but not on the `static long start...` or `long end...` declarations.

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, but to fix, do the following:

change

```
long end = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
System.out.println("Execution time was " + (end - start) + " ms.");
```

to

```
static {
  Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
  public void run(){
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    System.out.println("Execution time was " + (end - start) + " ms."); 
    }});
}
```

Comment: thank you Chuck! as all of you guys!

Answer (score 1):

You will get Syntax error on token when you have wrote all your java codes in the class itself without defining a method.

Solution for this type of issue is, simply create a method/ main method under the class and then code there..

This way will resolve the problem too.