# Java main class instance access

Tags: java, class, compilation, java-7, program-entry-point

I am not able to compile the following code. Not able to understand the compilation process here. why the main class instances are not been visible to other classes(**test1**). why it failing at compilation. Please help.

```
public class test {
    public int i = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println("test main");
    }
}
class test1 {
     test t = new test();
     System.out.println(t.i);
 }
```

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: How many files do you have? What is the exact content of each of them?

Comment: here is the error 
test.java:9: error: <identifier> expected
 System.out.println(t.i);
                   ^
test.java:9: error: <identifier> expected
 System.out.println(t.i);
                       ^
2 errors

Comment: @sp00m only 1 class. a normal java file.

Answer (score 7):

The `System.out.println(t.i);` statement should be within a block or method.

For example, you can ***either*** place it within a block (static or non-static, nevermind).

```
public class test1 {
    test t = new test();

    static { //static can be omitted
        System.out.println(t.i);
    }
}
```

***Or*** place is within a method

```
public class test1 {
    test t = new test();

    public static void printSomething() { //static can be omitted
        System.out.println(t.i);
    }
}
```

More info (thanks to @vidudaya):

- [Why does System.out.println() have to be inside a method ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901973/why-does-system-out-println-have-to-be-inside-a-method)

Comment: i want to know what is the problem with this. Will placing it in a static block work(compilation)?

Comment: Either place it within a block (static or non-static, nevermind) or within a method.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901973/why-does-system-out-println-have-to-be-inside-a-method)

Comment: thanks kocko. what i want to understand is the rationale behind it.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println(t.i);
```

must be inside some method.

```
public class Test {
    public int i = 10;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("test main");
    }
}


class Test1 {

    Test t = new Test();

    public void printI(){
        System.out.println(t.i);
    }

}
```

Also stick to java naming conventions. Class names must start with capital letters. variables and methods must be in camel case.